# Conveying “If any” as in "Her feelings, if any, were not shown."

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, locutions

How can *if any* be conveyed in cases like those below?

> Her feelings, if any, were not shown.
>
> She could take two of those candies, if any.

> What conditions, if any, must be placed on the undefined coefficients  if (a) matrix A is to be symmetric, and  matrix B is to be anti-symmetric?

“Le cas échéant” is rather formal, isn't it?

Comment: The candy one is equally odd. It normally would be something like: She took two candies, if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ***le cas échéant*** is slightly formal.

I would however use other expressions to render "if any" in your sentences:

- Her feelings, if any, were not shown.

> *Elle ne montrait pas ses sentiments, **si tant est qu'elle en eût**.* (formal)

- She could take two of those candies, if any.

> *Elle pourrait prendre deux de ces bonbons, **à l'occasion**.*

Answer (score 1):

Ses sentiments, **si elle en avait**, ne paraissaient pas.

**Si elle prend des bonbons** elles peut en  prendre deux de ceux-là.

*Comme la phrase précédente est un peu lourde on peut lui préférer la suivante, qui a le même sens.*

**Si elle prend des bonbons** ce ne peut être que deux de ceux-là.

Comment: The first sentence is odd, *n'apparaissaient pas* would be idiomatic. The third sentence hasn't the same meaning than the second one.

Comment: @jlliagre 1/ (TLFi) Être manifeste, être mis en évidence. Synon. éclater, surgir, ressortir. La vérité du sentiment paraissait dans les regards de Sara (RESTIF DE LA BRET., M. Nicolas, 1796, p.15). 2/ It is understated in the second sentence that there is no other possibility than the choice given; the third sentence is more categoric, that's all.

Comment: 1/ I didn't say it was incorrect but what was idiomatic in 1796 is not necessarily idiomatic today. [Dans le sens 1, la langue moderne préfère apparaître](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/para%C3%AEtre). 2/ You wrote *qui a le même sens*. This is incorrect.

Comment: @Lambie I found the English  sentences in books or sites. I cannot find the original source.

Comment: @Dimitris *The Diversity of Irony by Angeliki Athanasiadou and Herbert L. Colston, page 84: She is very emotional. Her feelings, if any, were not shown*.

Comment: @Dimitris You should provide the books you cite in your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Having post the questions some years ago, I suggest

> Her feelings, if any, were not shown.
>
> *Ses sentiments, si elle en avait, n'ont pas été montrés*.

and

> She could take two of those candies, if any.

> *Elle pourrait prendre deux de ces bonbons, éventuellement*.

Nevertheless, the first translation is a little bit 'cold' whilst the second one does not convey that 'if any' means possibly. [Thanks to @jlliagre.] For the third sentence I suggest

> Quelles conditions, le cas échéant (ou s'il y en a), doivent être placées sur les coefficients indéfinis si (a)
> la matrice A doit être symétrique, et (b) la matrice B doit être antisymétrique ?